# Accessing lazy global variable from API in stimulus framework

Tags: javascript, youtube, frameworks, global, lazy-evaluation

## I'm trying to make a [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/) controller which would access global [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pl) variable

Youtube Player API is lazy loading - it's class is loaded **asynchronously**

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

The problem is, that Stimulus doesn't want to access YT variable.

I tried to create a function, that loads script, and after it, runs given function, and imports it to stimulus

```js
export function loadScript (url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if (script.readyState) { // only required for IE <9
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else { //Others
        script.onload = function () {
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

But as you can see, it only creates new script object, so Stimulus still won't be able to access it.

### Is there a way in which I could make Stimulus access loaded script, and variables that are declared in it?

Here is a full controller code (don't mind bad practices, it's just a fast try):

```js
import {
    Controller
} from 'stimulus';

import $ from 'jquery';

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ['collapseButton', 'player']

    connect() {
        this.initPlayer();
    }

    initPlayer() {
        let player = $('#youtubePlayer');

        // Code taken straight from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pl
        player = new YT.Player(player, {
            videoId: 'Va297erJjJ4',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        var done = false;

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }

        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-player-modal" data-controller="youtubeplayer">
    <div id="youtubePlayer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a solution to your problem here, there you must first call the ready function and then give the callback.
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-browser-n3m3j?file=/src/Player.js

```js
// loadScript.js
import Player from "./Player";

function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if (script.readyState) {
    // only required for IE <9
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {
    //Others
    script.onload = function () {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api", new Player().initPlayer);


// Player.js
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

import $ from "jquery";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["collapseButton", "player"];

  connect() {
    this.initPlayer();
  }

  initPlayer() {
    let player = $("#youtubePlayer");
    window.YT.ready(function () {
      player = new window.YT.Player("youtubePlayer", {
        height: "360",
        width: "640",
        videoId: "Va297erJjJ4",
        events: {
          onReady: onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    });

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    var done = false;

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data === window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
      }
    }

    function stopVideo() {
      player.stopVideo();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div
      class="youtube-player-modal"
      data-controller="youtubeplayer"
    >
      <div id="youtubePlayer"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/loadScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Thank you for your effort!**

But I have a question:

If I understand correctly, you're importing a whole controller in loadScript.js, then invoking it, and inside of invoked controller, accessing the YT class from inside of window. Am I right?

Comment: @MateuszMoczydłowski Yes, you are right, here we are using the Modular approach, in your examples you also used this approach. We import the Player class from loadScript and together with the callback we give the Player method of the initialPlayer class, and when the Api is already available it will call this method inside the loadScript. When you add YouTube API in your YT variable page it becomes global,